# Show excel like data in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

I made a program that generates some data and want to show it in a grid like fashion like excel. What control should I use? I also want the user to be able to change the details if he wants to (like a textbox).

As an option step, is it possible to export this data to excel?

Thanks.

This is using c# and winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about DataGridView?
make sure you set the DataSource...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//generate your data
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you use c# with WPF, its rich UI element and plug-in are perfect for your purpose, you can use datagrid control to show your data in the excel fashion.

The excel export is simple, just use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel class.

Comment: -1 : An answer like that should at least include an example and more details. Otherwise it is a cop-out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I never programmed with such things before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Office Excel activeX control to view/edit excel documents.

Also [Excel Viewer](http://excelviewer.codeplex.com/) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like question #1 is answered, so I'll take a stab at question #2.

You can always save the gridview contents to a .CSV file format (comma separated values). Excel will automagically read that information into its workbook.